# NHibernate HQL with isnull() in where does not work

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I use the fallowing HQL-Query with NHibernate:

```
from Contact a where 
a.Id in (select x.Person.Id from PersonCompany x 
            inner join x.Company y 
            inner join y.Addresses z 
         where isnull(z.Street,'')+isnull(z.PostalCode,'')  Like :val)
```

In this query, NHibernate tries to convert :val (which is a string) to a double. 
z.Street and z.PostalCode are string-fields which can bee null. It looks like NHibernate has a problem with the first isnull() in the where-clause. when I use `z.Street+isnull(z.PostalCode,'')` it is working.
I have also tried `cast(isnull(z.Street,'')+isnull(z.PostalCode,'') as string)` but this is also not working, because NHibernate has a Problem with the cast-function (it generates more then two parameters).
Can someone help me, how I can solve this with NHibernate? - Perhaps there is another way to write the where-condition?

I use NHibernate 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `concat(coalesce(z.Street,''), coalesce(z.PostalCode,''))`

Comment: this genereates the fallowing where:  (isnull(addresses3_.Street+'')+isnull(addresses3_.PostalCode+'')) which throws an SqlException with message The isnull function requires 2 argument(s)

Comment: Try the new version. `isnull` is not registered for most dialects; `coalesce` is the standard. It might work when used on its own because NHibernate passes it through.